# Is there any way to update a var in JS (ajax) using HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So, I have the next code in HTML, my goal is to convert the location to Geocode (lat&long).

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward',
            data: {
                access_key: 'my private key',
                query: 'Thisshouldbeupdated(is my location e.g Transilvania,Romania)',
                limit: 1
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        var query = "";

        function update() {
            // find the input element by ID and assign its value to `myVarToUpdate`
            query = document.getElementById("").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input id="query" value="" />
        <button type="button" onclick="update()">Update</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

So, after I hit update (or submit) to update the var and to refresh and get the data from the PositionStack API.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give your form a way to identify it. Add an `id` or `class` to select the form. Remove the `onclick` event listener and change the button's type to `submit`.

```
<form id="query-form">
  <input id="query" value="" />
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

You'll need to be able to call the `$.ajax` request every time you submit your form. The easiest way to do this is to wrap the AJAX request in a `function`. Let's call this function `getPosition`. Give the function a single parameter called `query`. This parameter is the string that we'll send to the server when calling the `getPosition` function.

```
function getPosition(query) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward',
    data: {
      access_key: 'my private key',
      query: query,
      limit: 1
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  });
}
```

Now connect the form and the `getPosition` function.
Select the form and the query `input`. Listen to the `submit` event on the form element. This event is triggered whenever you press a submit button inside a `<form>` element.

While submitting, get the value of the query input. Then call the `getPosition` function while passing the `query` value.

```
const $form = $('#query-form');
const $query = $('#query');

$form.on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Don't submit, but do our custom behavior.
  const query = $query.val();
  getPosition(query);
});
```